# Formula to look up multiple cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have tried all diff types of vlookup with Ifs and xlookup and even index and match but I am having no luck at all.

What I am trying to do?

I need a formula that can take "race type" from column and "jockey" from another column and then look on a separate sheet to find the race type and jockey and take the value.

All the examples on here the values are only in one column mine are across 5/6.

So example

Racetype = Handicap Chase  , Jockey = Joe Bloggs

It will then look for Joe Bloggs and Handicap Chase on separate sheet and take the Percentage for him.

[racetype and jockey data you can see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BCV88.png)

[diff sheet want to find the abovd racetype and jockey and take value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2QY0X.png)

have tried this from suggested post but no luck][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/snkit.png)

so I want to take the race type and jokcey from screenshot 1 and check the sheet in screenshot 2 and match up the racetype and jockey to get the value

Hope I have made it clear. Hope someone can help.

Many thanks

Jason

Comment: the suggestion did not help

Comment: Please provide a [mre] in text form, not as picture of text. Please describe why the proposed duplicate does not answer your question. Show how you tried, the best attempt and explain how those attempts failed. And please, take the [tour] and read [ask]. Try https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/21/find-a-simpler-problem/ i.e. try to first only do simpler parts and test that they work, before combining them.

Comment: I have added how I have tried in screenshit

Comment: what more do you want for me, just want some help

Comment: Yeah that jockey doesn’t, because he has only had a few rides, I only put on other sheet jockeys with a big enough sample.

Comment: All names are spelt correct as they are taken from pivot table that comes from that data

Comment: If you can get the names to match properly then use an INDEX/MATCH/MATCH: `=INDEX('Jockey NH Rating'!C:I,MATCH(Combined!N1017,'Jockey NH Rating'!B:B,0),MATCH(Combined!E1017,'Jockey NH Rating'!C$1:I$1,0)`  But this assumes that the race types on `Jockey NH Rating` are in row 1 if not change that to the correct row.  Also it assumes that the cells match exactly.

Comment: I have changed the duplicate target.

Comment: @BigBen if you noticed I found another of mine :)

Comment: See? If you give reasons why a duplicate is not helpful, then people react. If the new duplicate proposal does not help either explain again. (I was wrong your question did not get reopened, but I think this also counts as getting you help.) Have fun.